# Cannot customize Eclipse perspective with SWT_GTK3

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

When I'm using Eclipse with the SWT_GTK3 UI, I can't enter some of the UI parts, for example the Eclipse Marketplace or Window -> Perspective -> Customize Perspective.

This problem doesn't appear when running `env SWT_GTK3=0 eclipse`.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

I'm running Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) on Arch Linux, GTK 3.20, OpenJDK 1.8.0_77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse 4.5.x has several bugs in GTK 3.20.
I'm also on Arch, and had to force GTK2 for Eclipse to be usable.
For example, this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490891 is fixed on master (Eclipse 4.6). I don't know if this will be backported to 4.5.